# ORACLE left outer join issue (with empty table?)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm wondering why this query:

```
select l.objectID LEFT_CODE, r.object_code RIGHT_CODE
from OGGETTO_ORGANIZZATIVO l left outer join
    ANAG_OGGETTO_ORGANIZZATIVO r on l.objectID = r.objectID
WHERE r.objectID IS NULL;
```

returns some rows, while this other query

```
select l.objectID LEFT_CODE
from OGGETTO_ORGANIZZATIVO l left outer join
    ANAG_OGGETTO_ORGANIZZATIVO r on l.objectID = r.objectID
WHERE r.objectID IS NULL;
```

doesn't return nothing.
My problem is insert in right table all the rows present in left table but not in right table; at the moment the right table is empty.

It seems that if I am not referring the right field in the select clause, oracle will not manage the outer join.

Thanks in advance.
Paolo

**[UPDATE]**
*First Query*

```
select l.codice_oggetto_SAP
from oggetto_organizzativo l left outer join
  ANAG_OGGETTO_ORGANIZZATIVO_SAP r
    ON l.codice_oggetto_sap = r.codice_oggetto_SAP
WHERE r.codice_oggetto_sap is null
```

Execution Plan
[image]

*second query*

```
select l.codice_oggetto_SAP, r.codice_oggetto_SAP
from oggetto_organizzativo l left outer join
  ANAG_OGGETTO_ORGANIZZATIVO_SAP r
    ON l.codice_oggetto_sap = r.codice_oggetto_SAP
WHERE r.codice_oggetto_sap is null
```

Execution Plan
[image]

the first execution plan statement `(NULL IS NOT NULL)` seems to me curious...

**[SECOND UPDATE]**
@toddlermenot,

But why this WORKS???:

```
CREATE TABLE LEFT_TBL
   (    "OBJECTID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)  ) ;

CREATE TABLE RIGHT_TBL
   (    "OBJECTID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)  ) ;

INSERT ALL
  INTO LEFT_TBL (OBJECTID) VALUES ('AAA')
  INTO LEFT_TBL (OBJECTID) VALUES ('BBB')
  INTO LEFT_TBL (OBJECTID) VALUES ('CCC')  
SELECT * from DUAL;

SELECT l.objectID
FROM LEFT_TBL l LEFT OUTER JOIN RIGHT_TBL r
  ON L.OBJECTID = r.OBJECTID
WHERE r.OBJECTID IS NULL;
```

witt this execution plan

```
Plan hash value: 2059691840

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |     3 |    72 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN ANTI    |           |     3 |    72 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| LEFT_TBL  |     3 |    36 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| RIGHT_TBL |     1 |    12 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("L"."OBJECTID"="R"."OBJECTID")

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Could be and Index problem?

Comment: The behavior you describe would be a bug.  Can you reproduce it on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Which version of Oracle?

Comment: But gut feeling.. Oracle will not do this `blunder`.. Atleast in Oracle 11g it works fine.. [Fiddle Reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e942b/5)

Comment: Interesting. Could this be a bug caused by CBO taking a shortcut it is not supposed to take?. Could you please post the execution plans of both the queries?.

Comment: @joe: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @Gordon. On SQL fiddle I create two dummy table with one varchar(20) fields each, populate just one with three records and run statement. It WORKS!! Therefore, I run the same script on my Oracle, AND IT WORKS again. I thinsk there is something in my table definition that create confusion so SQL engine... see my update above. Thanks!

Comment: @PaoloUrsini: Whoa! Is that the *complete* explain plan for the first query or it has been cut in the screenshot? Also, the screenshot shows the *explain* plan which might not always be the same as *execution* plan, but still the difference shows something is off.

Comment: @toddlermenot: Yess, this is the complete explain plan.. I am new to Oracle, now I study and when I understand how to get Execution plan I will post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have posted the *explain plan* which might differ from the actual *execution plan*.
Difference is *explain plan* is just what optimizer (CBO) *thinks* it will follow during the actual execution of the query which might deviate from the real *execution plan*.

With that said, If your *explain plans* are to be believed, then this definitely seems to be an **optimizer bug** as I hypothesized in my comment. 
For some reason in your first query, CBO is taking an *incorrect* shortcut and ignores the `LEFT OUTER` join (the right table is NOT accessed at all) and uses the strange `NULL is NOT NULL` predicate as the final filter which is always going to be `FALSE` meaning that your final result set is always going to be empty.

To resolve this, you might want to raise a ticket with Oracle support and patch your database to get this bug fixed.

**EDIT:** If the statistics on both the tables are out of date, gather stats on both tables and try rerunning the query. CBO might take the correct plan after the stats are collected. Statistics being out of date is still however not an *excuse* for CBO to choose an incorrect execution plan. You might want to do this after you raise the ticket to Oracle Support, so that this incorrect behavior is still reproducible when they work on it.

Comment: @PaoloUrsini: It seems like you are using SQL Developer tool and the tab says it is "Explain Plan" in the screenshot. There are multiple ways to get the actual execution plan: One common way is to use dbms_xplan.display_cursor -> http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_interp.htm#TGSQL94854.

Comment: first af all, thanks a lot! I update the post with a second situation similar to the one that gave me the issue, but that actually works!!! Perhaps would be really a statistic problem :-( I will interest my DBAs to ask Oracle support
Thanks again.

Comment: You are very welcome. I have to agree there with you that this issue is specific to your case and not reproducible with a fresh set of tables like Maheswaran Ravisankar's SQL Fiddle. This is why I advised you to gather stats only after the Oracle support folks work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Bug 10269193 - Wrong results with outer join and CASE expression optimization (CASE need not to be present) or LIKE operator (Doc ID 10269193.8)

Product (Component)

Oracle Server (Rdbms)

Range of versions believed to be affected

Versions >= 11.2 but BELOW 12.1

Symptoms:

Related To:

- Internal Error May Occur (ORA-600)
- Wrong Results
- ORA-600 [kkfdjoi:kkfdnpart_DIM1]